# How to merge Class Libraries Projects into Executable

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, executable, class-library

I have solution with few Class Libraries and one Executable Project.
Business logic is good splited into class libraries and i dont want permanently move files from libraries to executable project in my solution.

But i must have one executable file as result without any libraries.
What is the good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/61/combining-multiple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe-for-a-wpf-application

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tip from Jeff Richter's blog for another way of creating single file executables using the AssemblyResolve event hook + manifest streams:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx